# Routing in LEO satellite networks

Tags: networking, satellite

I am going to do project in routing for  LEO satellite networks.

How well does QUALNET work for Satellite network simulations?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done very much with it till now, but as far as i can say, I cant recommend it.

I dont know if it fits your purpose as well, but you may want to take a look at [itrinegy](http://www.itrinegy.com/index.php/solutions/by-task/satellite-link-simulation) , but that may be just a personal preference.